# C# Data Contract for a json response where the response itself is a List

Tags: c#, json, datacontract

I Have a data contract Like following:

```
public class responseObject<T>
{
    public T responseBody;
    public T response
    {
        get { return responseBody; }
        set { responseBody = value; }
    }
}
```

the above is the json response where the responseBody is of type "T".
But now the challenge is, for one particular API the response itself is a List :

```
{
 "statusMessage": "OK",
 "statusCode": 200,
 "response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "xyz",  
    }
   ]
}
```

hence it doesnt go with the base contract anymore.

Please suggest a work-around. I dont want to change the above contract because it goes fine with all other API's json response.

Comment: you need to deserialize json to `responseObject<List<SomeClass>>` where `SomeClass` is a class with two properties `id` and `name`

Comment: You should follow the [.NET Naming Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). For your properties, decorate them with [DataMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1) `[DataMember(Name = "Response")]`

Comment: Can you share the code for deserialize the result into the object?